# How to show buttons instead of dropdown for variants selection in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

How to show buttons instead of drop-down for variant selection in Magento 2 of configurable product like example, if I have created a color variant with values Red, Black & White and selects Dropdown while creating Attribute. So when I've checked the front end it will show me a dropdown with above values, but I need to show buttons instead of dropdown.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the attribute **color** (Stores > Attributes > Product) and change **Catalog Input Type for Store Owner** from "Dropdown" to "Visual Swatch"